# How to set basic authentication mode to token based in kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have been following [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control#basic) kubernetes github and to change basic to token based authentication. It says to change

> --authentication-mode=basic 
>  to 
>   --authentication-mode=token

but my question is where to change? which file? which yml?

It would really great if you provide an example of yaml configuration file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--authentication-mode` flag is for kubernetes dashboard. Add/Change this flag in kubernetes dashboard deployment.

If you are using [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui) to deploy kubernetes dashboard, then add/change flag in the deployment yaml.

```
# ------------------- Dashboard Deployment ------------------- #

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard
        image: k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        args:
          - --auto-generate-certificates
          - --authentication-mode=basic
          # Uncomment the following line to manually specify Kubernetes API server Host
          # If not specified, Dashboard will attempt to auto discover the API server and connect
          # to it. Uncomment only if the default does not work.
          # - --apiserver-host=http://my-address:port
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
          mountPath: /certs
          # Create on-disk volume to store exec logs
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-volume
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            scheme: HTTPS
            path: /
            port: 8443
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
        secret:
          secretName: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
      - name: tmp-volume
        emptyDir: {}
      serviceAccountName: kubernetes-dashboard
      # Comment the following tolerations if Dashboard must not be deployed on master
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule

---
```

Comment: can you please provide the example?

Comment: @SandeepKumar added example yaml

Comment: still in login page i can see the **skip** option, I want to get rid of it. configuration is changed but I don't see any change.

Comment: @SandeepKumar If you want to disable *skip* button, then  add `--disable-skip=true` flag.(ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Dashboard-arguments)